# Direction of Drag Force when coming down a steep road

Tags: forces, drag, free-body-diagram

[image: Drag Force]

If a car is moving down a steep road, and we are allowed to ignore friction but not air resistance, which direction is the drag?

For example in the image, the drag is opposite of the motion of the skier going down. Is this incorrect if used for a large mass like a car?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes.  Drag force is like friction, it acts in the opposite direction which you are going.  In fact, drag force is the air resistance force by Newton’s third law.  Even a large object like a ship on the sea experiences drag force, also known as buoyancy, which is equal to the weight of water which it  displaces.  The same would apply to any object.

However, you mentioned something wrong in your question.  Frictional force cannot be ignored, or else the car will be sliding, not rolling.